# Word - STOP template reloading - DON'T want styles to update

Tags: templates, ms-word, styles

I have a `doTx` file containing custom styles. I open it and save as a new `doCx`. I modify and update a style, e.g. make it red, then save the file. When I reopen the file, the style has gone back to black, which I DON'T want.
If I look at the `VBA` I see that in addition to `Project(docx-name)`, `Project Template(dotx-name)` has loaded. I suspect that if I stop the template from reloading the style won't change back. Can anyone help?

Comment: Go to `Developer Ribbon -> Document Template`. Is `automatically update document styles` ticked? If so, untick and try again. If you have no developer ribbon then go to `File -> Options -> Custom Ribbon` and tick the developer ribbon.

Comment: Thanks @Mr JF - been away from this project for a while but will have another look soon.